# API-Gateway Swagger Extension: how to use them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am struggling to understand how to use the Swagger Extension for the API Gateway:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html

I am using the Import/Export RestAPI via AWS CLI, but cannot find any example of how to use them from command line. Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example via the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/import-rest-api.html)

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --body 'file:///path/to/API_Swagger_template.json' --region us-west-2
```

Edit: here is a swagger example with extensions: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer/blob/master/tst/resources/swagger/apigateway.json

Comment: Kohn -AWS, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have used that, but the imported swagger file does not have the Integration methods defined on each endpoint. The sample swagger file can be found here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer/blob/master/tst/resources/swagger/petstore-expanded.json  What I am trying to understand is whether/how I can use this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html#api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration to add my own "x-amazon-apigateway-integration". Thanks

Comment: Sure, the apigateway.json example in that repo has integration extensions

Comment: Thank you, yeah I believe I should have explained a bit better what I am trying to do, my apologies. I know that the apigateway.json has the integration extensions, but I will be working with swagger files which will not come with the integration extensions included and I am trying to understand whether I can "add" the integration methods via the API-Gateway swagger extension from AWS-CL. Is that achievable? With no integration method, my deployment consistently fails. Ultimately, CodeDeploy will take care of my CD process. Thank you, once again - really appreciated.